# Text editor and text-file-based hyperlinks

Tags: vim, emacs, editor, text-editor, hyperlink

**Background:**

It seems that some text editors and IDEs are starting to get more "browser-like" in their features. Specifically, one such feature is the ability to treat ordinary text in an open text buffer as a hyperlink to another file, resource, or even a runnable command.

**Programming this as an editor plugin or macro**

Since this seems like a good idea, I have started programming some scripts and editor addons to do this very kind of thing, so that the user of a text editor can open or operate on links of the following style:

```
href="c:/files/foobar.txt"                   (click to open file)
href="c:/files/foobar.txt" jumpto="34"       (jump to a line number)
href="c:/files/foobar.txt" find="Lorem"      (jump to 1st line containing word)
href="find_in_files://c:/files" find="Lorem" (show all matching lines)
[[find_in_files://find=Lorem;exten=*.htm*]]  (alternate syntax option)
href="redir://c:/files/feebar.txt"           (replace current edit buffer)
href="run://c:/files/foobar.jpg"             (open in default image editor)
[[run://c:/files/foobar.jpg;runwith=foo.exe]] (alternate syntax option)
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there any kind of emerging convention for forming text-based hyperlinks?
2. If there is a convention for this kind of thing, is there a published specification?
3. Is there an implementation of this idea in your favorite editor/IDE?
4. Is there an alternate pre-existing approach for this idea that does not use hyperlinks?
5. How is this feature handled in the "grand-daddy" editors? (Vim, Emacs)

**Update:**

It looks like the question could have been clarified, but it turns out that Emacs Org mode is one specific example of what I was looking for that answers all of my questions.

Comment: @Roger Pate @Matt: Thanks for your responses. I disagree with the "problem does not exist" issue though. Perhaps I should have said "lightweight markup language" instead of "plain text" (although one can easily quibble on that as well). There are a zillion different Wiki Engines with their own syntaxes, some of them follow published standards. There's no general reason to assume what I asked here could not be similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs' Org-Mode has support for all kinds of [Hyperlinks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Hyperlinks.html).

Comment: Thanks, accepted answer because this actually gives a specific example of what I am referring to in a real-world text editor.

Comment: +1 for mentioning an awesome mode for which I've seen no clone anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

There are several script for Vim that add hyperlinks and markup.  One of the most popular is [Viki](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=861).

Answer (score 3):

1. URLs, such as http://example.com/ (notice SO automatically links that), and sometimes a "www." prefix, just because it's so common.  Email addresses are another example commonly recognized.

   - But not this quasi-xml-attribute stuff you have.
2. Of course not; once you try and make plain text follow some convention, you no longer have plain text.
3. Yes, see #5.
4. Yes, see #5.
5. It's extremely common for editors, especially programmers' editors, to have scripts, macros, tools, or whatever-they-want-to-call-it.  Usually these are not controlled directly by the text in the file, but may use the file, filename, selection, cursor position, directory of the current file, etc.  I expect many good programmers use such features without thinking about them anymore.

Mostly it sounds like you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Roger Pate **//Of course not; once you try and make plain text follow some convention, you no longer have plain text//** Not sure what this is referring to. If this means that "plain-text" is a misnomer for "formatted text", then we could reconvene with a mutual understanding that this misnomer can be replaced with "capable of being modified in a standard text editor".  XML, YAML and JSON are examples of what was meant in the OP.

Comment: @Roger Pate **// it sounds like you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist//** Not really, just doing research for a feature that may already exist. It's not a problem, especially for those who do not need or use such a feature.

Answer (score 2):

Surely the `jumpto="34"` and `find="Lorem"` could be replaced with web-browser-style `#` and `?` marks.

So your second and third example would look like so:

```
href="c:/files/foobar.txt#34"       (jump to a line number)
href="c:/files/foobar.txt?Lorem"    (jump to 1st line containing word)
```

Although, as Roger Pate says above, it does sound like you're solving a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to avoid "above" or "below" since the order will change depending on how the page is viewed (oldest, newest, votes), depending on current vote totals, and depending on which answer is eventually accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs also has "find-file-at-point", which you can invoke with M-x ffap

Answer (score 1):

See also [LinkD](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LinkdMode). Nothing fancy like Org. Simple, small.